# JavaFX MediaPlayer "OnEndOfMedia" not working in runnable jar file

Tags: events, audio, javafx, media, executable-jar

If I load an audio file from a package in the project and start it via IDE then the method setOnEndOfMedia() is working properly. But when I export my project to a runnable jar file (Eclipse library handling = extract) it is not reacting at all. It is reacting when loading the file from a default directory but I want to load it as a ressource from my package. Here's a sample code:

```
public class MediaTest extends Application
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        launch();
    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage)
    {
        Button button1 = new Button("from outside");
        Button button2 = new Button("from package");
        primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(new HBox(button1, button2)));

        button1.setOnAction(e ->
        {
            Media media = new Media("file:/C:/sample.wav"); //use any audio
            MediaPlayer player = new MediaPlayer(media);
            player.setOnEndOfMedia(() -> System.out.println("End of Media"));
            player.play();
        });
        button2.setOnAction(e ->
        {
            Media media = new Media(ClassLoader.getSystemResource("sounds/sample.wav").toExternalForm()); //use any audio
            MediaPlayer player = new MediaPlayer(media);
            player.setOnEndOfMedia(() -> System.out.println("End of Media"));
            player.play();
        });

        primaryStage.show();
    }
}
```

Comment: Is the file located inside the same package like the `Application` class?

Comment: No, it's not. But if I put it into the same package the result does not change.

Comment: Why are there two buttons to load the audio file?

Comment: It is just a sample code. The buttons simplify testing for you. Like I explained, when exported as runnable jar, loading it from outside behaves correctly, loading from package sadly not.

Comment: What does the stacktrace tell you when you run it from the terminal?

Comment: Nothing. There is no exeption thrown. The event does not fire. You could run my sample code by your own.

Comment: I tried it and it runs for me. Can you add your project structure to the question?

Comment: Ok, but what do you mean by project structure?

Comment: To clarify, the audio loads and plays both in the IDE, and running from the jar file, correct? But when running from the jar file the `onEndOfMedia` handler is not invoked. Is that correct?

Comment: @James_D Yes, correct. But it is only not invoked, when loaded as ressource (the right button).

Comment: What happens if you programmatically extract the resource to a temporary file, and then initialize the media from the file? I wonder if there is some issue with knowing the length of the content if it's not a file url (some media sources are streams, of course, though it should be able to determine it's not a stream if loading from a resource).

Comment: I tried that now, creating a tempFile via File.createTempFile() and loading the data from the resource in it using InputStream and OutputStream. The tempFile then behaves like is was the original file and therefore the onEndOfMedia event is invoked correctly.

Comment: This is really strange since it prints `End of Media` when I try to run it from the jar.

Comment: Well, that sucks for me. I have still no idea, why that special case does not work. I can't even debug since it works when used with IDE. Creating them as temporary files is just a stopgap.

Comment: Now I used a different .wav file downloaded in web to see if it's the file's fault. Same situation with the new file but it does not start playing at all! Even worse.